# Java class with method that accepts list of any object

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a class that can be made without any parameters, and has a method that takes a list of any object and behaves like this:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"a","b"});
List<String> result1 = myClass.myMethod(list1);

List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {1,2});
List<Integer> result1 = myClass.myMethod(list2);
```

Here's my attempt after reading briefly about Java generics:

```
public class myClass<T> {

public List<T> myMethod(List<T> input) {
  ... 
  return input; // just an example
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ..., tried making the method static but that results in more errors

Comment: Ahh, I miss read your example.  Two things, the class name shoul start with a capital (`MyClass`), second you would need to add the `static` modifier to the method.  See my answer below and an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you put the parameter on the class, but really only need it on the method.  Try:

```
public class MyClass {

  // this is a parameterized method
  public static <T> List<T> myMethod(List<T> input) {
    ... 
    return input; // just an example
  }
}
```

Comment: good point, but still have the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ..."

Comment: You may have seen my example before my second edit.  There should be the `static` modifier on the method.

Comment: that solved it, thank you very much. i'll accept the answer once the timer is over